# Invalid URI in request and apache stopps working

Tags: apache-http-server, denial-of-service

Today our apache stopped working, he did not crash but stopped to response.

The only error i can see in the error_log is this:

```
[Thu Feb 11 10:00:05.245233 2016] [core:error] [pid 7496] [client 169.229.3.91:54481] 
AH00126: Invalid URI in request 2p[\x96(\xc0\xf6\xb6w\x89\xf2=\xcd\x8f\xa4i\x9c\xb6\xec<n\v\x11!W\xdc\x9f\x1c\xdd8?\xb4\xe0\xb6,eW\xf0K\xa0H\xd1-\x91\x9f
```

accesslog contains the same

```
linux-9jgs:/home/USER # cat /var/log/apache2/access_log |grep 169.229.3.91
169.229.3.91 - - [11/Feb/2016:10:00:05 +0100] "2p[\x96(\xc0\xf6\xb6w\x89\xf2=\xcd\x8f\xa4i\x9c\xb6\xec<n\v\x11!W\xdc\x9f\x1c\xdd8?\xb4\xe0\xb6,eW\xf0K\xa0H\xd1-\x91\x9f" 307 264 "-" "-"
linux-9jgs:/home/USER #
```

any idea how we can prevent apache from hang-up next time?

We are using this version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Linux/SUSE)
Server built:   2015-08-11 15:51:30.000000000 +0000
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:36
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider

- Upgrading to Apache webserver [latest version](https://httpd.apache.org/) (2.4.18 at time of writing)
- Reviewing security-related settings
- Use of modules such as [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/about.html)

See [Secure Your Apache With mod_security](https://www.howtoforge.com/apache_mod_security)

---

Another action that might be worth trying would be to change the MPM from prefork to worker in the hope that it might be less vulnerable to this problem.

See [How do I select which Apache MPM to use?](https://serverfault.com/q/383526/55524) and [Understanding Apache 2 MPM (worker vs prefork)](https://www.garron.me/en/blog/apache2-mpm-worker-prefork-php.html)